# In TextMate, can you have a command go to a line in a file? (Alternatively: Can it do a Find for a specific string?)

Tags: textmate

I often want to find uncommented `print` statements in my (Python) file. I have a simple regex `^\s*print` that does the job. Is there a way to assign this to a keyboard shortcut so it will  Find the next uncommented print, without me having to enter the regex?

My first thought was to create a command that will find it, but I don't have a way to move the cursor to the line once I find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Macro feature](http://manual.macromates.com/en/macros) inside TextMate:

1. Go to Bundles > Macros > `Start Recording` (⌥⌘M)
2. Perform a single find command with your regex
3. Go to Bundles > Macros > `Stop Recording` (⌥⌘M)
4. Go to Bundles > Macros > `Save Last Recording` (⌃⌘M)
5. Save your macro with a suitable name and keyboard shortcut into which ever bundle you like. A nice idea would be to save it into the default Python Bundle, so that the keyboard shortcut is only available when you have a Python file open.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize Macro recording would record stuff like that.